# Iterate and update BindingList items using a one-liner

Tags: list, foreach, compact-framework, bindinglist, compact-framework2.0

I have a **BindingList** I want to update certain items,but in order to use the **Foreach** available only for the **List<>** I have to initialize a new **List** with the **BindingList** items. like this:

```
new List<ScanData>(ScanDataList)
.FindAll(i => i.Badge == badge)
.ForEach(x =>x.EmpName = empname);
```

And that's the simplest way I found to do it, but I don't want to start with the **New** keyword, is there any other simpler way to Iterate over the **BindingList** items and update them using a one-liner like the above? (I put it in three lines for readability).
Id like just to remove the **New** keyword but that just doesn't work, 
if a new function helps that is also acceptable, if its generic for any **BindingList** would be perfect.

- Note: Im using compact framework 2.0
- I don't want to initialize a variable Im not gonna use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit silly. There's no reason you have to do it in one line of code and avoid declaring a variable. If you use the new operator you are initializing an instance of an object, regardless of whether you are declaring a variable for it or not.

That being said, I do not know what your ScanDataList is... There's a linq expression equivalent to FindAll called Where which may be more efficient than FindAll (because it doesn't have to create a new list, it just lazily iterates). If your ScanDataList is already IEnumerable then you can probably do something like this...

ScanDataList.Where(i => i.Badge == badge).ToList().ForEach(x=>x.EmpName = empname);

Even if your ScanDataList is not enumerable, you could implement an extension method of your own to help you accomplish this, but it seems like a lot of work for something that can easily be achieved without arbitrary unnecessary constraints (no new, no variables, etc).

So to clarify, I would probably use .Where LINQ expression because it is probably a bit more efficient because it doesn't need to create a new List. However, using that same logic, I'd probably avoid ToList() and separate your code into two lines with something like.

```
foreach(Employee emp in ScanDataList.Where(i => i.badge == badge))
  emp.EmpName = empname;
```

This way, no additional list is created.